# How to copy data from other user address space then current task

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I  have kernel task that create kernel thread ,and I need to copy data to the user which call my kernel task ,from my kernel thread . So I can pass the current task as parameter to my kernel thread.
But how can I tell the `copy_from_user` function to copy from other process address space.
this my kernel task

```
 asmlinkage  int sys_daniel(struct pt_regs *r )
 {
       struct task_struct *ts1;
       ts1 = kthread_run(kthread_func, current, "thread-1");
       return 0;
   
  }
```

and this the kernel thread I am tring to write

```
static int kthread_func(struct_task args)
 {

   spcail_copy_to_user(from,to,len,args->mm)
  }
```

there is any way to edit the kernel thread current->mm or to set in the `copy_from_user` the address space.

Comment: As a side note: your example code doesn't make much sense... it's invalid, it won't even compile.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli why not?

Comment: `static int kthread_func(current->mm args)` because `current->mm` is invalid type.

Comment: Well, for starters, `static int kthread_func(current->mm args)` makes no sense. Other than that, you are using variables that are not defined anywhere. I get that it is an example, but it could be made a little bit clearer IMHO.

Comment: "I need to copy data to the user which call my kernel task ,from my kernel thread" - You cannot do that by normal means. A thread may operate only with the memory it has access to. Instead, re-design your driver to perform that copying inside `sys_daniel` function.

Comment: @Tsyvarev why not the kernel can access all physical memory

Comment: @Tsyvarev isnt it possible to add something to the kernel thread mapping?

Comment: "why not the kernel can access all physical memory" - Well, kernel may have an access to all physical memory but only if it is mapped. It is possible to adjust mapping inside Linux kernel, but it is not so simple procedure. If you are new in the Linux kernel programming, it is better to avoid that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it quiet necessary in my case do you have  some links I can use?

Comment: I don't know links which describe that in a simple manner, sorry. May be, someone else could help you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok I figure it out  so I found the user page with the get_user_pages then I can add it through kmap thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so you first need to create a page object with the address you want so I used the

```
     struct page *P
     get_user_pages(current,current->mm,(unsigned long)buff,1,1,&p,NULL)
```

so this basically  create page that now we can map to the kernel
so we can use

```
kernlBuff=(char*)kmap(p);//mapping it to the kernel
kunmap(p);//for unmapp it from the kernel
```